# Getting raw binary from mixed Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Having following nodeJS *Buffer().toString('utf8')*:

```
Content-Type: audio/x-ms-wma
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=recordedAudio
\r\n\r\n0&�u�f�\u0011��\u0000�
```

I need to remove headers (Content-Type/Disposition) and get the raw audio data. If I simply replace headers with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method I am not able to convert UTF-8 audio back to *Buffer* properly.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to convert to strings here. To get body intoa  buffer search for `\r\n\r\n` within your buffer and then take a slice from that point.

For example:

```
var buf = ...;
var body = null;
for (var i=3; i<buf.length; ++i)
{
    if (buf[i]=='\n' && buf[i-1]=='\r' && buf[i-2]=='\n' && buf[i-3]=='\r')
    {
        body = buf.slice(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

keep in mind that `body` will reference the same memory as your buffer (e.g. there is no memory copied).

Answer (score 0):

I made it working using [buffer-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-split) package:

```
var bsplit = require('buffer-split');        
var rawData = bsplit(rawDataWithHeaders, new Buffer('\r\n\r\n'))[1];
rawData = bsplit(rawData, new Buffer('\r\n'))[0];
```